Can くらい mark subject?
A salaryman was very tired and fell asleep beside 田山さん. On the next day, he recalled what happened yesterday and said

田山さんの前で寝るくらいヤバかったんだ

I initially interpreted this くらい as ほど and it means "(yesterday) was crazy that I slept in front of Tayama." But I am not sure whether I should rule out the possibility that くらい might mean something like は or のが. In this case, this sentence will be understood as "the fact that I slept in front of Tayama was crazy." I wonder if it is possible to interpret this くらい as subject marker like this or it is always understood as ほど.
Here is a similar example from one of my recent questions: 楓くらいユルイ方が良いんだよ. Can it be understood as 楓はユルイ方が良いんだよ?

In general, yes, 寝るくらい can be a subject. In your specific case, no, that 寝るくらい is unambiguously adverbial, and it only means "to the point where I sleep".

If the sentence was, say, 田山さんの前で寝るくらい大丈夫だよ, it would most likely be understood as meaning sleeping in front of Tayama-san is OK, rather than something is OK to such a degree that you even sleep in front of Tayama-san (whatever that might mean in an actual scenario). However, this is not because くらい works as a topic marker. It's simply that は is omitted in informal speech.

田山さんの前で寝るくらいは大丈夫だよ.

くらい here adds a sense that sleeping in front of Tayama-san is not a big deal and you would be forgiven even if you did that.
Similarly, 楓くらいユルイ方が良いんだよ could be interpreted the same as:

楓くらいはユルイ方が良いんだよ

It would mean that you would like it if at least Kae was "loose" while you accept that other girls probably aren't.
I find it hard to interpret 田山さんの前で寝るくらいヤバかったんだ that way.
